# How to use deferLoading if we don't know the total amount of entries in the database?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am currently working on a project, where I display every virtual machines available on Azure. As there is a lot of data, I would like to use deferLoading from DataTable. The thing is, either I use deferLoading with integer value, or array value, in both cases, I don't know what is the total amount of entries in the database (the database is sometimes updated, and the total amount of entries subject to change).

So I am wondering how could I handle this ?

While waiting to find a solution using deferLoading, I am also trying to change de drawCallback option, to change the function called when clicking the "Next" or "Previous" buttons. So I would only load 25 new entries in the datable, which would replace the data already present in the datatable.

Another way to solve my problem is to use a static table, but I won't have all the possibilities that a DataTable can offer.

Here is the current JavaScript code :

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    pageLength: 25,
    /*
            
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    deferLoading: [25, x],
            
    */
    drawCallback: function() {
        // .off() disables the regular action of #table_<name> button
        // so the program will only execute the function we want.
        $("#table_next").off().click(function(event) {
            showNextVMs();
        });
        $("#table_previous").off().click(function(event) {
            showPreviousVMs();
        });
    }
});
```

Do not hesitate to share any advice, I never used DataTables before, I may miss some good practices.

Comment: I've used DataTables a lot of times but never with serverSide rendering. If you haven't already done, I'd suggest you to post your questions on their discussion forum too, as it's active, definitely focused and often also the DT team directly answers to questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @cheesyMan, I posted my answer on DataTables Forums. [Here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/206178) is the link to the answer.